# How do you include DatatablesJS and AngularJS within RequireJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, requirejs

I have returned several errors when trying to add data tables to my project. Maybe I just don't understand requireJS as well as I should because I am extremely confused about the use of shims. Is a shim used in place of a `define` function in a single JS file? I understand that Angular uses it's own dependency injections but why can you not so easily add a shim for Angular? If you don't have to use shims, then can you substitute with nested `require` functions? Can you help me determine how I would need to add dataTables and potentially Angularjs?

Below are the errors that are returned when I try to define a concatenated version of data tables. This files includes minify, single file, CDN, no jquery, bootstrap, no styling library, datatables, buttons, flash export, html5 export, JSZip, pdfmake, Print view, keyTable, responsive, and scroller. I downloaded this file from https://www.datatables.net/download/index and decided to have the file concatenated because adding a shim for each option was taking too much work. When I remove my own custom .js files the error about a mismatched anonymous define() module gets removed but the error about pdfmake stays around.

`Uncaught Error: Script error for "pdfmake"`

`Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (E){return h(E,window,document)}`

shop-depends.js (require configuration file):

```
require.config({
baseUrl: '/vendors/',
paths: {
    jquery : "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min",
    custom: "custom", 
    "shop-js": "/build/js/shop-js",
    iCheck: "iCheck/icheck.min",
    'datatables.net': "https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jszip-2.5.0/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.13/b-1.2.4/b-flash-1.2.4/b-html5-1.2.4/b-print-1.2.4/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.0/r-2.1.0/sc-1.4.2/datatables.min",
    fancybox: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox",
    bootstrap: "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min", 
    fastclick: "fastclick/lib/fastclick",
    vfs_fonts: "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts",
    ngprogress: "nprogress/nprogress"
},
shim: {
    'jquery': {
        exports: 'jquery'
    },
    'shop-js':{
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'bootstrap': { 
        dep:['jquery'],
        exports: 'bootstrap'
    }
}
}); 

require(['jquery'], function($){

require(['iCheck'],function(){ 

});

//require(['buttons.html5']);

require(['datatables.net'], function(){ 
        require(['custom', 'shop-js']);
    }); 

        //require('datatables-net-bs');
require(['fancybox', 'bootstrap', 'pdfmake', 'vfs_fonts', 'ngprogress', 'fastclick']);
//requirejs(['angularMain'],function(){

});
```